# What is the maximum size limit for SOAP response for JAX-WS?

Tags: web-services, soap, jax-ws

This is regard to my question  On JMeter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789323/jmeter-exception-response-code-000-response-messageread-timed-out-for-java-we)

i found the SOAP message size can be a problem for the exception.

What is the size limit of SOAP response for JAX-WS webservices?.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing in the JAX-WS specification about this. If there is a limitation, I'd say that it is dependent on your JAX-WS implementation. If you need to send really big files (hundred or thousand of MB), maybe consider using MTOM/XOP.